# Regex password validation for non-sequence data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, model

I'm attempting to validate that my passwords may not contain any sequential characters such as "123" or "abcd" etc. I'm new to regex and i'm trying to do it by having the following code in my User model:

```
  validate :password_complexity

  def password_complexity
    if password.present? and not password.match(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d). /)
      errors.add :password, "must include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one digit"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I doubt it is a task for a regex. You need to write special checks for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably somewhat outside the bounds of regex. I would recommend looking into [zxcvbn](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/), which has also been ported into [a ruby gem of the same name](https://github.com/envato/zxcvbn-ruby) and even exists as [a devise plugin](https://github.com/bitzesty/devise_zxcvbn). This will provide you with significantly more robust verification. You may also consider just inspecting the code for these projects, for inspiration, if you are determined to learn how one might implement something like this from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this isn't a job for a regex: maybe you could do it but it would be very complicated.  Here's how i would do it.

```
def contains_sequential_characters?(string)
  sequential = false
  string.split("").each_with_index do |char,i| 
    if (string[i+1] == string[i]+1) && char =~ /[a-y0-8]/i
      sequential = true
    end
  end
  sequential
end
```

At the heart of this solution is that calling an array index on a string (eg `"foo"[2]`) will give you the ascii code of the character at that position.  We only care about ascii codes that are next to each other between a-z and 0-9, which is why i'm also matching the *first* character against a-y (not z) and 0-8 (not 9).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex, which will accept a minimum of 13 digits and will not accept either sequential digits or sequential characters:

```
(?=.*?[0-9])(?!.*((12)|(23)|(34)|(45)|(56)|(67)|(78)|(90)|(01)))(?=.*?[a-zäöüß])(?!.*((ab)|(bc)|(cd)|(ef)|(fg)|(gh)|(hi)|(ij)|(jk)|(kl)|(lm)|(mn)|(no)|(op)|(pq)|(qr)|(rs)|(st)|(tu)|(uv)|(vw)|(wx)|(xy)|(yz)))(?=.*?[A-ZÄÖÜ])(?!.*((AB)|(BC)|(CD)|(EF)|(FG)|(GH)|(HI)|(IJ)|(JK)|(KL)|(LM)|(MN)|(NO)|(OP)|(PQ)|(QR)|(RS)|(ST)|(TU)|(UV)|(VW)|(WX)|(xy)|(yz))).{13,}
```

Comment: The vast majority of parentheses only harm execution speed and readability without providing any value at all.